# I want to sql script input string and value in database is number?

Tags: sql, database, sql-scripts

I want to sql script in select

input string and value in database is number?

EX.

Input: Wait Approve

```
ApproveStatus(nvarchar)
"0"
"2"  
"4"...
```

ApproveStatus = 2 It's "Wait Approve"

I want sql script find value "Wait Approve" in ApproveStatus and Output is fields ApproveStatus = 2

*This first in questions*

Comment: cant understand what you are asking here " input string value in database is number"

Comment: i think you should add a new column like description,,,then you can select id from it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Given the following data:

```
CREATE TABLE statuslookup (
    id int unique,
    label nvarchar unique
);
INSERT INTO statuslookup (id, label) values (2, 'Wait Approve');
```

Then if you need to convert from label to id:

```
SELECT id FROM statuslookup WHERE label = 'Wait Approve';
```

Hopefully that at least gets you started.....